# Type erasure in C++: how boost::shared_ptr and boost::function work?

Tags: c++, boost, type-erasure

Type erasure - is that how you call it?

How `boost::shared_ptr` stores its deleter and how `boost::function` stores its function object?

Is there any tutorial that teaches the trick?

What is the run-time cost of using type-erased function objects?

Comment: did you try to google before asking? there is plenty of informantion on the web. the old Thamas Becker article: http://www.artima.com/cppsource/type_erasure.html or this well known book: http://www.boostpro.com/mplbook/ and lots of other resources.

Comment: @GeneBushuyev: the entire purpose of SO is basically to make Google searches unnecessary. If you want to learn about some programming-related subject, you can Google it, and either (1) find a SO answer, or (2) get unreliable information which may or may not be correct and help you. Or you can (2) search/ask for it on SO, and get answers that are peer-reviewed, rated by quality, and virtually guaranteed to be useful. Please don't tell people to Google instead of asking questions here. It's counterproductive.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The idea is simple, you define a base class that has an interface with the functionality you need, and then inherit from it. Since the *type erased* class uses only that interface, the actual type underneath is *forgotten* and *erased*. Alternatively, if the only needed interface can be expressed as free functions you can store pointers to the free functions.

```
namespace detail {
   struct deleter_base {
      virtual ~deleter_base() {}
      virtual void operator()( void* ) = 0;
   };
   template <typename T>
   struct deleter : deleter_base {
      virtual void operator()( void* p ) {
         delete static_cast<T*>(p);
      }
   };
}
template <typename T>
class simple_ptr {
   T* ptr;
   detail::deleter_base* deleter;
public:
   template <typename U>
   simple_ptr( U* p ) {
      ptr = p;
      deleter = new detail::deleter<U>();
   }
   ~simple_ptr() {
      (*deleter)( ptr );
      delete deleter;
   }
};
```

This is a really simplified smart pointer, but the idea is there. In the particular case of `shared_ptr`, the *deleter* is stored as part of the reference count object, that is held by pointer.

Comment: shared_ptr deleter doesn't have to be derived from anything.

Comment: @pic11: The deleter passed in to the `shared_ptr` does not need to inherit, *but* type erasure is implemented by using inheritance (or function pointers) internally.

Comment: How you call a function object if you don't know its static type and/or it doesn't inherit from a base class?

Comment: @pic11: [Here's a recent answer I gave that used type erasure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6122094/building-boostoptions-from-a-string-boostany-map/6123962#6123962), take a look so you can get an idea of what David is talking about, in code.

Comment: Shouldn't `deleter` derive from `deleter_base` in this example? At the moment it doesn't.

Comment: @Sjoerd: Thanks, you are right, I missed the inheritance relationship (together with the namespace...).

Comment: Thanks everyone. I need some time to digest the material.

Comment: @David In the `simple_ptr` destructor you call `operator()`, but `deleter` is a pointer, so the line should read `(*deleter)(ptr);`. Maybe it would be better to have a normal member function instead of `operator()`. I usually call these one-purpose-type operations with a witty name like `doIt()`, `execute()` or `makeItHappen()` :-)

Comment: from first para of your answer : `the actual type underneath is forgotten and erased` <-- couldn't understand that, please explain in easy term? Thanks

Comment: @Mr.Anubis: The type of the `shared_ptr`/`function` does not reflect the type of the `deleter`/functor that was used to create it. When you get a `shared_ptr` or `function` objects, the types used to create it are no longer available.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I apologize for late reply. Can you please go little easy on me? . I understood the example i.e interfaces and virtual function does the magic under the hood and how thing are working but you words/sentences don't gets in to my mind e.g `the types used to create it are no longer available.`

Comment: @Mr.Anubis: Maybe easier with an example: `void f( shared_ptr<int> )`, and two shared pointers: `shared_ptr<int> p( new int ); int i; shared_ptr<int> q(&i, noop_deleter);` (assuming the appropriate deleter). The deleters do not take part in the type of the `shared_ptr`, which means that you can do both `f(p)` and `f(q)`. Compare that with `std::unique_ptr` where the deleter is a template argument: `void f( unique_ptr<int> )`, and `unique_ptr<int,noop> q( &i )`, then `f(q)` is an error. The type of the deleter is part of the type of the smart pointer.

Comment: ... in the first case, the type of the deleter is *erased* and the type of the smart pointer does not reflect it, in the second case, the type of the deleter is part of the type of the smart pointer.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas cool!!,  that example made everything more clearer, thanks a lot for quick help and your patience :)

Comment: This answer is good for illustration, but it actuality don't the semantics of `shared_ptr` require `p` to be captured in the deleter-capturing-helper-class, not supplied later?  (perhaps `std::shared_ptr` and `boost::shared_ptr` differ in this regard)