# Why can't C++11 move a noncopyable functor to a std::function?

Tags: c++, function, lambda, c++11

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
struct A
{
    A(){}
    A(A&&){}
    A& operator=(A&&){return *this;}
    void operator()(){}

private:
    A(const A&);
    A& operator=(const A&);

    int x;
};

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
int main()
{
    A a;
    std::function<void()> func(std::move(a));
}
```

'A::A' : cannot access private member declared in class 'A'

It seems like when I capture something by reference or `const` I can make a non-copyable lambda. However when I do that it actually works to give it to a `std::function`.

Comment: As a [workaround](https://gist.github.com/vmilea/5815777), you could put a copyable adapter between std::function and your functor. The adapter has a dummy (move-on-copy) copy constructor and throws if copied.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The short answer is that the C++11 specification requires your `A` to be `CopyConstructible` to be used with `std::function`.

The long answer is this requirement exists because `std::function` erases the type of your functor within the constructor.  To do this, `std::function` must access certain members of your functor via virtual functions.  These include the call operator, the copy constructor and the destructor.  And since these are accessed via a virtual call, they are "used" whether or not you actually use `std::function`'s copy constructor, destructor or call operator.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong (and probably I am) but, in order to use virtual functions, you need a vtable and hence a base class. Which is the base class in this case?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6324694/type-erasure-in-c-how-boostshared-ptr-and-boostfunction-work for a description of how type erasure works.  The base class is an implementation detail of std::function.  The derived class is also an implementation detail, but is also templated on the supplied functor.

Comment: @HowardHinnant: Do you think if someone proposed an ammendment to granulate the requirements so it's per-operation it would go through? (Only require `A` be copy-constructible if the `std::function` is copied.)

Comment: @GManNickG:  The only chance it would go through is if there was an accompanying implementation that clearly demonstrated it could pass all existing unit tests and had a sufficiently friendly copyright license.  Personally I currently do not know how to create such an implementation.  But the thing I love about this industry is that I'm always learning something new. :-)

Comment: as a nice C++14 workaround you can use the `fu2::unique_function` class from https://naios.github.io/function2/ which is both a move-only type and allows moving non-copyable callables into it, a typical example of which would be a lambda move-capturing a non-copyable object in its context

Comment: @HowardHinnant std::function throws an exception if it is empty. It could do the same for an empty copy constructor.

Answer (score 0):

`std::function` requires functors to be copyable.

This is an arbitrary design decision. Possible alternatives could be:

- Non-copyable functors are allowed, but attempting to copy the resulting `std::function` causes a crash/exception.
- Non-copyable functors are allowed, and `std::function`s themselves are always non-copyable.
- ...

It's impossible to only require copyability if the resulting `std::function` is copied, because it can be copied in a different TU (translation unit).

So, if you ask me, the current behavior is the lesser evil.

Answer (score -3):

It's a bug in Visual Studio. It attempts to ellide a copy (when actually it should be trying to ellide a move), which requires an accessible copy constructor. The best solution is simply to declare the copy constructor/assignment operator and never define them. The class will still be non-copyable but the code will compile, because VS will never attempt to actually call the copy constructor.

Comment: It apparently does try to call the copy ctor if I do as you suggest, because I get an unresolved external for it.

Comment: @Dave: Yes, that's why it is a *bug*. The standard says that it should be allowed, but VS doesn't do it right.

Comment: @NicolBolas That's fine, but his workaround suggestion didn't work. I'm not allowed to say that? (I do appreciate the answer though DeadMG, thanks)

Comment: The bug you mention exists (and is pretty damn annoying) but this is not the problem here.