# How is std::function constructed for a lambda

Tags: c++11, lambda, std-function

I am a bit confused by how `std::function` is constructed at a given lambda. The constructor of `std::function` is listed [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/function). Which one is actually used to capture a lambda? Is it `template< class F > function( F f );`? Looks like I can't construct `std::function` with a lambda that captures non-copy-constructible objects. Why is this necessary for lambda capture?

```
// fu is an object of type std::future 
std::function f = [future=std::move(fu)]() {...}  // compile error

// foo is an object of type int
std::function f = [foo=std::move(foo)]() {...} // compile ok
```

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25421346/how-to-create-an-stdfunction-from-a-move-capturing-lambda-expression

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that the standard states only copyable function objects can be stored in a `std::function`.  This is unsatisfactory: why?

`std::function` is a copyable type.

The standard states that when copied, it also copies its contents.

"But", you say, "I never copy it.  Why should it need be copied?"  An instance of `std::function` records *how to copy* its contents even if it never does so.  It typically uses a technique known as type erasure.

Here is a toy example:

```
struct invoke_later {
  struct i_impl {
    virtual ~i_impl() {}
    virtual void invoke() const = 0;
    virtual std::unique_ptr<i_impl> clone() const = 0;
  };
  template<class T>
  struct impl:i_impl {
    T t;
    ~impl() = default;
    void invoke() const override {
      t();
    }
    impl(T&& tin):t(std::move(tin)) {}
    impl(T const& tin):t(tin) {}
    virtual std::unique_ptr<i_impl> clone() const {
      return std::make_unique<impl>(t);
    };
  };
  std::unique_ptr<i_impl> pimpl;

  template<class T,
    // SFINAE suppress using this ctor instead of copy/move ctors:
    std::enable_if_t< !std::is_same<std::decay_t<T>, invoke_later>{}, int>* =0
  >
  invoke_later( T&& t ):
    pimpl( std::make_unique<impl<std::decay_t<T>>( std::forward<T>(t) ) )
  {}

  invoke_later(invoke_later&&)=default;
  invoke_later(invoke_later const&o):
    pimpl(o.pimpl?o.pimpl->clone():std::unique_ptr<i_impl>{})
  {}

  ~invoke_later() = default;

  // assignment goes here

  void operator() const {
    pimpl->invoke();
  }
  explicit operator bool() const { return !!pimpl; }
};
```

the above is a toy example of a `std::function<void()>`.

The operation of copying is *stored* in the `->clone()` method of the `pimpl`.  It must be compiled *even if you never call it*.

The writers of the `std` specification where aware of the above technique, and knew its limitations, and wanted to permit `std::function`s to be implemented simply using it.  In addition, they wanted simple operations on the `std::function` to behave in predictable ways: with non-copyable contents, what should copying the `std::function` do?

Note you can get around this issue by wrapping your state in a `shared_ptr`.  Then copyies of your `std::function` will simply store shared references to your state, instead of copies.

```
template<class F>
auto shared_state( F&& f ) {
  return [pf = std::make_shared<std::decay_t<F>>(std::forward<F>(f))]
    (auto&&... args)->decltype(auto) {
      return (*pf)(decltype(args)(args)...);
    };
}
```

now:

```
std::function<Sig> f = shared_state([future=std::move(fu)]() {...});
```

will compile and work.

An alternative approach is to make a non-copyable `std::function` and use that instead of `std::function`.

Finally, whe working with `future`, a `shared_future` is a copyable `future` type and may be cheaper than doing a `shared_state`:

```
std::function<void()> f = [fu=fu.share()]{ /* code */ };
```

Comment: For `future`s in particular, `.share()` may be cheaper.

Answer (score 1):

A lambda that captures a move-only object by value becomes itself move-only, which makes sense since it contains said object.

But [std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) has to be [copy-constructible](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/CopyConstructible) and [copy-assignable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/CopyAssignable), which means that it can only contain copiable objects.