# How to capture a unique_ptr in a std::function

Tags: c++, c++14

I need to move a `unique_ptr` to a `std::function` closure. I'm using [generalized lambda captures](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/cpp14-language#lambda-captures) in C++14.

```
auto ptr = make_unique<Foo>();

// Works.
auto lambda = [p = move(ptr)] { };

// This does not compile.
std::function<void()> func = [p = move(ptr)] { };
```

It's trying to copy, rather than move, the lambda capture into the `std::function`. The relevant error is:

```
 copy constructor of '' is implicitly deleted because field '' has a deleted copy
      constructor
  std::function<void()> func = [p = move(ptr)] { };
```

The example [here](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/cpp14-language#lambda-captures) would make this seem to work.

Note that the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236521/how-to-capture-a-unique-ptr-into-a-lambda-expression) just repeats the example on isocpp.org.

I can move to a `shared_ptr` as follows:

```
shared_ptr<Foo> s = move(ptr);
```

but that creates another issue, because I need to call a function that expects a `unique_ptr` from within my lambda, and I can't convert a `shared_ptr` back to a `unique_ptr`.

Is it possible to capture a `unique_ptr` in a `std::function`?

Comment: *"It seems that std::function needs a move constructor for functors"* And your lambda has a move constructor. If that was enough, you could `std::move` your lambda into the `std::function`. The problem is that `std::function` requires the functor to be copyable, because `std::function` itself can be copied.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat right ok. Will remove that.

Comment: A `std::function` which calls a function which requires a `unique_ptr` can mostly be called only once :/ . So inner function should probably not expect a `unique_ptr`.

Comment: very related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25421346/how-to-create-an-stdfunction-from-a-move-capturing-lambda-expression

Comment: Even if you never copy `std::function`, it requires that the callable it holds can be copyable. `std::function` actually does move the lambda into its storage, but it doesn't compile, because the lambda isn't copyable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## std::function objects can all be copied

`std::function` is a type-erasure object that supports copying the object stored.

When you store a `std::unique_ptr` in a lambda, that lambda does not support being copied.

So `std::function` quite rightly complains.  It is a type that can be copied, and when passed in something is works out how to copy it.  "I cannot copy it" isn't a valid answer; all `std::function`s can be copied.

## Industrial strength solution:

There are two common approaches to solve this problem.  First, you store the `std::function`'s state in a `std::shared_ptr` of some kind.  Second, you write or find a non-copying `std::function` and use that instead.

More "modern" `std::function` replacement libraries support a number of useful things:

1. function views, that do not own what they wrap.
2. move-only function objects, that don't support copying.
3. multiple-overload function objects, that support more than 1 signature at once.
4. fixed-sized buffers, that fail to compile if there isn't enough automatic storage instead of heap allocating.
5. trivially copyable function objects

I've personally had a need for every one of the above for various special purposes.

Then you'd use `moveonly_function<void()>` when you don't need to copy the callable, and your code compiles.

However, this is probably too heavy for your needs right now.

## A quick solution is:

```
template<class F>
auto make_shared_function( F&& f ) {
  return
   [pf = std::make_shared<std::decay_t<F>>(std::forward<F>(f))]
   (auto&&...args)->decltype(auto)
   {
     return (*pf)( decltype(args)(args)... );
   };
}
```

now whenever you run into this problem:

```
// This does not compile.
std::function<void()> func = make_shared_function([p = move(ptr)] { });
```

and the state of the callable object is now stored in a shared ptr.

Comment: Super cool, how would you write this with std::invoke ?

Comment: @jyavenard I do not understand your question.  Where do you propose to use invoke, and replacing what?  In tge lambda inside make shared function?

Comment: in place of `(*pf)( decltype(args)(args)... );`

Comment: @jyavenard `std::invoke( pf, decltype(args)(args)... );`

Answer (score 2):

Since C++23 you can now employ [std::move_only_function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/move_only_function) to achieve what you are looking for. `std::move_only_funciton` allows you to assign a lambda with moved variables inside a capute block to it.

```bash
$ g++ -std=c++23 -o output_file main.cpp
```

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>

struct Foo
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;

    void Print()
    {
        std::cout << "Foo::Print is called" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct Caller
{
    std::move_only_function<void()> func;
};

int main()
{
    auto ptr = std::make_unique<Foo>();
    int a = 5;

    // This will compile since C++23.
    std::move_only_function<void()> func = [p = std::move(ptr), a]
    {
        p->Print();
        std::cout << "A is " << a << std::endl;
    };

    Caller o;
    o.func = std::move(func);
    o.func();
    return 0;
}
```