# Is it a good idea to initialize lambda function arguments with move?

Tags: c++, lambda, move-semantics

I used to write lambdas like this:

```
std::vector<....> data;
//here we're populating data

mylambda=[data{std::move(data)}](...){...}

...
std::function<....> myfunction= mylambda;
...
return myFunction
```

At first, this seemed like an ok solution, but recently I found that, after being called, std::function calls `reset` function, which re-initializes the parameters of the lambda function. This seems like something that could potentially cause problems (since when reset is called, `data` variable is already out of context), but so far I haven't had any issues with this.

Is initializing lambda parameters by moving an object which does out of context a good idea?

Comment: What is the purpose of the code? What is the actual problem you need to solve? Are you okay with `data` becoming empty (since you *move* the data)?

Comment: Also note that you capture by *value* which means (without a move) the `data` for the lambda is a *copy* of the (local?) variable `data`. Even with the move, the lambdas `data` is still by *value* meaning it retains its contents as long as the lambda object is alive.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude isn't `data{std::move(data)}` calling move constructor for data? yes, I'm totally ok with data becoming unavailable, I'm using this construction to push data processing to another thread

Comment: `data{std::move(data)}` what is the purpose of this capture?

Comment: @artm I'm moving data to the function that is going to be processing it in another thread

Comment: Did you try move construction the `std::function`? `std::function<....> myfunction= std::move(mylambda);`

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov yes, I usually move functions instead of copying them

Comment: I tried this both with and without move: `myfunction= std::move(mylambda)`. In both cases compiler requires the class that you move into the lambda to have a copy constructor (why?). But in caseof moving the lambda into the function the copy constructor is never called.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25421346/how-to-create-an-stdfunction-from-a-move-capturing-lambda-expression