# How to transfer unique_ptr ownership efficiently through many layers of calls to async scenario

Tags: c++, c++17

Let me start with background context.

Often time, in server side programming, our function call may go async (i.e. to shift the work to another thread in callback because of IO). So the pattern is function A calls B, B calls C and eventually in many layer deep down in function Z, we may decide to go async.

Function A needs to transfer ownership managed by a unique_ptr by using `std::move` all the way to function Z. However, move `unique_ptr` is 40 nsec (vs 20 nsec passing `shared_ptr` by value or 1 nsec for passing raw pointer). For extremely perf sensitive server application, we may not want to do `unique_ptr` move through so many layers of functions. For similar reasons, we don't want to use `shared_ptr` (more importantly `shared_ptr` always messes up ownership).

To be clear, we can use raw pointers and manage the resource ourselves. We always have that option and it could ultimately be the best option. But for the sake of argument, I think there is another option that I want to get people's opinion on.

So the proposed pattern is to pass raw pointer from the `unique_ptr` all the way from function A to Z. At function Z where I need to go async, I create a new `unique_ptr` based on the passed raw pointer and move to the new thread (i.e. I can capture the raw pointer in lambda, and create the new `unique_ptr` in lambda's body and execute the lambda in new thread). At function A, if there is no exception thrown (i.e. the transfer succeeded), I will call release on `unique_ptr` so there is no double release. If there is exception, then I will not call release so the caller in A will free the unique_ptr's resource. This way, I avoided a chain of move of unique_ptr and still be able to. See example below.

```
void Foo1(MyObj* po)
{
  auto l =[po](){ auto u = std::unique_ptr<MyObj>(po); };
  std::thread t(l);
  t.join();
}

int main() 
{
  auto p1 = std::make_unique<MyObj>();
  Foo1(p1.get());
  std::cout<<"i am here\n";
  p1.release(); 
}
```

Comment: If you have a question to ask, you'd better add it before this Question gets closed for being "unclear what you're asking"

Comment: _"... move unique_ptr is 40 nsec (vs 20 nsec passing shared_ptr by value..."_ that's strange, moving unique_ptr is 2 assignments, where as  passing shared_ptr  by value  will involve a lock to update the reference count as well as creating the new shared_ptr..

Comment: This is probably going to get opionion based answers.

Comment: Please explain how you measured moving `unique_ptr` as taking twice as long as `shared_ptr`. There's no reason why, in an optimized build, moving an ordinary `unique_ptr` should be slower than passing a raw pointer.

Comment: Why aren't you moving the `unique_ptr` into the lambda via capture?

Comment: @RichardCritten: "*passing shared_ptr by value will involve a lock to update the reference count*" No `shared_ptr` uses locks for incrementing the reference count. Also, move-construction doesn't change reference counts.

Comment: @alter igel, sorry I have one more requirement, I need to be able to push the lambda to containers. if I capture unique_ptr, I can't push it because it requires it supports copy constructor which unique_ptr doesn't support. It is a well known limitation.

Comment: @NicolBolas re the lock - making the reference count multi-thread safe; re move-construction - OP: _"... passing shared_ptr by value..."_

Comment: @RichardCritten: Passing by value means you're passing a value, not necessarily copying one. You can move by value. And no, you only need atomic increments to make `shared_ptr` thread-safe. Which is what every implementation uses. They're not "locks".

Comment: @Kenneth: "*it requires it supports copy constructor*" What container imposes copy-constructible on its type? Not even `vector` requires that. Also, how do you store a lambda of all things in a `vector`?

Comment: @NicolBolas how do you pass by value without taking a copy?

Comment: @RichardCritten: You move into the function: `func_that_takes_by_value(std::move(some_value))`.

Comment: @alterigel you can look at https://github.com/kennthhz/testingground/blob/master/src/smart_ptr_example.cc for how I compare pass share_ptr, unique_ptr and raw. just use steady_clock and call a series of function with std::move(unique_ptr<T>).

Comment: @TedLyngmo yes I am soliciting opinions. I know this is not black and white thing.

Comment: @NicolBolas the OP specified move for the unique_ptr and pass by value for the shared_ptr - I assumed he used different terms because he is passing the pointers by 2 different methods/techniques.

Comment: @RichardCritten: Then it's not a proper comparison if you're not doing the same thing on both sides. Equally importantly, there is *no way* that two atomic increments & copying two pointers and nulling two out is *faster* than copying a single pointer and nulling out the other one. So obviously the OP is not timing their code correctly.

Comment: @RichardCritten look at this link on limitation I mentioned https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25421346/how-to-create-an-stdfunction-from-a-move-capturing-lambda-expression

Comment: It seems my question relies on my benchmark showing pass std::move(unique_ptr<T>) through a series of function calls is more expensive than pass share_ptr<T> by value and raw pointer. But several of you questions my benchmark data. My code is at https://github.com/kennthhz/testingground/blob/master/src/smart_ptr_example.cc   I use the same approach for raw, share and unique_ptr. Did I miss anything obvious? See MeasurePassUniquePtr.

Comment: @Kenneth [This is what I got](https://quick-bench.com/q/qJDZJaenJMp3084k6AT5m33UKgA) - In my test, `shared_ptr` is 120 times slower. Moving a `unique_ptr` is just a tad slower than passing the raw pointer. I must admit that I didn't look closely at the tests you made. Perhaps you can make something in quick-bench too? Otherwise you might get tricked by the optimizer removing parts of the tests if it can see that it doesn't have any observable effect.