# Cannot pass std::unique_ptr in std::function<>

Tags: c++, function, lambda, unique-ptr

```
#include <functional>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

void foo(std::function<void()> f)
{
    f();
}

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<int> handle = std::make_unique<int>(5);
    foo(
        [h = std::move(handle)]() mutable
    {
        std::cout << *h << std::endl;
    });
}
```

Following code doen't compile with error

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\functional(914,58): error C2280: 'main::<lambda_1aa523ba59bbecea5306bc1fd178120f>::<lambda_1aa523ba59bbecea5306bc1fd178120f>(const main::<lambda_1aa523ba59bbecea5306bc1fd178120f> &)': attempting to reference a deleted function

1. Why it is happen?
2. Is there are way how pass std::unique_ptr in std::function<void()> without passing it by reference?

Comment: You can't copy a `unique_ptr` the copy constructor is deleted for it.

Comment: `std::function` does copy.

Comment: If  ```std::function<void()>``` is a must then you probably need to pass the pointer ```[h = handle.get()]()```

Comment: @Jarod42, when std::function made copy of unique_ptr<>? If replace on
void foo(std::function<void()>&& f) problem reproduce too

Comment: @PeterDevenyi, that is minimal reproducable example, in real case i should pass lifetime of unique_ptr to lambda

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `std::function` requires the function object to be Copy-Constructible, so you can't expect a lamdba to be moved to it. On initialization, it attempts to copy the lambda and so the `std::unique_ptr` with it, which is a member of this lambda, and, expectedly, fails to do so. What you can do is store your lambda in a variable and pass it to function that accepts `const std::function&` using `std::ref` like that:

```
        void foo(const std::function<void()>& f); // function declaration
        auto a = [h = std::move(handle)]() mutable
        {
            std::cout << *h << std::endl;
        };
        foo(std::ref(a));
```

This is a related question with much more detailed answers: [How to create an std::function from a move-capturing lambda expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25421346/how-to-create-an-stdfunction-from-a-move-capturing-lambda-expression)

Comment: Thanks, it's help me. This soltution work even void foo() take f by copy

Comment: you don't have to change `foo`, however you do need to be careful about how it uses `f`, as after `foo` ends the reference inside copies of `f` will dangle