# Why does unique_ptr take two template parameters when shared_ptr only takes one?

Tags: c++, c++11, std, shared-ptr, unique-ptr

Both [`unique_ptr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/unique_ptr/) and [`shared_ptr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr/) accept a custom deleter to call on the object they own. But in the case of `unique_ptr`, the deleter is passed as a template parameter of the *class*, whereas the type of `shared_ptr`'s custom deleter is to be specified as a template parameter of the *constructor*.

```
template <class T, class D = default_delete<T>> 
class unique_ptr
{
    unique_ptr(T*, D&); //simplified
    ...
};
```

and

```
template<class T>
class shared_ptr
{
    template<typename D>
    shared_ptr(T*, D); //simplified
    ...
};
```

I can't see why such difference. What requires that?

Comment: My guess is that the reason is that as an unique_ptr can only constructed once by one "person" while a shared_ptr might be used and passed around all over the programm and thus be constructed with different args.

Comment: `shared_ptr` type-erases the deleter, i.e. users of `shared_ptr` don't have to know what type the deleter has. This has a run-time cost (allocation, dereference), so it isn't performed for `unique_ptr` (which is overhead-free). E.g. see http://stackoverflow.com/q/6324694/420683

Comment: @dyp: Maybe expand that into answer, including a brief tutorial on type erasure? Although it does not answer _why_ the same approach was not chosen for `unique_ptr`... Does it?

Comment: @dyp Ok, but why does `shared_ptr` do that?

Comment: @Nemo `shared_ptr` has to store a bookkeeping object anyway, so it already requires an additional allocation (when not using `make_shared`). Also, it is sometimes useful to be able to use `shared_ptr`'s reference counting mechanism with pointers not under *the* shared ownership of the bookkeeping object.

Comment: @qdii `shared_ptr` implies shared ownership. It doesn't require of all owners to know how to destroy the object, and that's probably already good enough a reason to provide this type erasure. The overhead also isn't much larger because of the bookkeeping object.

Comment: @dyp I am a bit skeptical because C++ moto is "pay for what you use": type-erasing the destructor has a cost so there should be solid reason why it is needed. What do you mean by "it doesn't require of all owners to know how to destroy the object", isn't that the definition of shared-ownership that any of the owner might have to destroy the object?

Comment: @qdii IIRC there are implementations of `shared_ptr` that have virtually no overhead for the type erasure, as they just combine it with the overhead required for a bookkeeping object. -- Although any owner might be required to destroy the thing owned by the `shared_ptr`, the owner doesn't need to know *how* to do that, i.e. it doesn't need to see neither the definition nor the declaration of the release function of that owned thing.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

If you provide the deleter as template argument (as in `unique_ptr`) it is part of the type and you don't need to store anything additional in the objects of this type.
If deleter is passed as constructor's argument (as in `shared_ptr`) you need to store it in the object. This is the cost of additional flexibility, since you can use different deleters for the objects of the same type.

I guess this is the reason: `unique_ptr` is supposed to be very lightweight object with zero overhead. Storing deleters with each `unique_ptr` could double their size. Because of that people would use good old raw pointers instead, which would be wrong.

On the other hand, `shared_ptr` is not that lightweight, since it needs to store reference count, so storing a custom deleter too looks like good trade off.

Comment: "you can use different deleters for objects of the same type": Do you mean that the standard wanted to allow two different `shared_ptr` pointing to the _same object_ to be destructed different ways?

Comment: *"If deleter is passed as constructor's argument (as in shared_ptr) you need to store it in the object"* Although it might not require additional storage; if the deleter is stateless it can be encoded in the type of the bookkeeping object.

Comment: @qdii - no, not the same object, but different shared_ptr of the same type.

Comment: @WojtekSurowka wait, if they are pointing to different objects of the same type T, passing the destructor as a class parameter is enough to let the user call different destructors for each of them. Just use `std::shared_ptr<T, D1>` for the first one, and `std::shared_ptr<T, D2>` for the second one.

Comment: @qdii: You need to imagine a function that takes a `shared_ptr` as argument, or an object that stores a `shared_ptr` as a member variable. Not having to care about the deleter makes them more flexible.

Comment: Let's say I have a big system which uses shared_ptr<T> and there are many functions accepting such pointers. If I introduce the second template argument, I would need either to make those functions templates, or to duplicate them.

Comment: @WojtekSurowka, @Nemo, true, but in the case of `unique_ptr` it didn’t bother anyone: if I have `foo( const std::unique_ptr<T>& )`, then introducing the templated destructor brings the same problem: duplicate those functions or make them template.

Comment: It is all about tradeoffs. unique_ptr is not supposed to have any overhead, so the complication you described is a necessary cost. In the case of shared_ptr some overhead is already there, so it could be designed in more flexible way.

Comment: @qdii: You are not talking about `shared_ptr`s of the same type.  Since they have different types, they can't be mixed in the same collection.

Comment: If `shared_ptr` took two template arguments you could still write `shared_ptr<T, function<void(T)>>`, so I don’t really see why this would be so good.

Comment: And that little type-erasure the `shared_ptr` does allows for doing some amazing things. I find that trade-off to be quite worthwhile all in all.

Comment: @WojtekSurowka Insightful answer. I forgot that template arguments actually "enhance" a type, giving it more nuances. "it is part of the type" Meaning that another `unique_ptr` without custom deleter wouldn't have the same type as the former right?

Answer (score 3):

Shared pointers of *different types* can share the ownership of the *same object*. See [overload (8)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr) of `std::shared_ptr::shared_ptr`. Unique pointers don't need such a mechanism, as they *don't share*.

```
template< class Y > 
shared_ptr( const shared_ptr<Y>& r, element_type* ptr ) noexcept;
```

If you didn't type-erase the deleter, you wouldn't be able to use such a `shared_ptr<T, Y_Deleter>` as a `shared_ptr<T>`, which would make it basically useless.

Why would you want such an overload?

Consider

```
struct Member {};
struct Container { Member member };
```

If you want to keep the `Container` alive, while you use the `Member`, you can do

```
std::shared_ptr<Container> pContainer = /* something */
std::shared_ptr<Member> pMember(pContainer, &pContainer->member);
```

and only have to hold onto `pMember` (perhaps put it into a `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Member>>`)

Or alternatively, using overload (9)

```
template< class Y > 
shared_ptr( const shared_ptr<Y>& r ) noexcept; 
  // Only exists if Y* is implicitly convertible to T*
```

You can have polymorphic sharing

```
struct Base {};
struct Derived : Base {};

void operate_on_base(std::shared_ptr<Base>);

std::shared_ptr<Derived> pDerived = /* something*/
operate_on_base(pDerived);
```