# Why can't unique_ptr infer the type of the deleter?

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr

Let's say I want to use a custom deleter with an unique_ptr:

```
void custom_deleter(int* obj)
{
    delete obj; 
}
```

Why do I have to write this:

```
std::unique_ptr<int, void(*)(int*)> x(new int, custom_deleter);
```

instead of this:

```
std::unique_ptr<int> x(new int, custom_deleter); //does not compile
```

?

Can't the type of the deleter be inferred?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21355037/why-does-unique-ptr-take-two-template-parameters-when-shared-ptr-only-takes-one

Comment: Template classes don't infer template parameters. Only template functions do.

Comment: I wonder why `std::make_unique` doesn't have an overload in which you can specify the deleter. This way, you can infer the type of the deleter.

Comment: @vsoftco I was looking at the docs just now and wondered the same thing...

Comment: @vsoftco How would that work? It has to take an argument pack to construct the `T`. How would you differentiate which one of `Args...` is the `Deleter`?

Comment: @Barry: It could be done with a type tag. For example, a 'deleter' template class that contained the deleter, or a tag that always preceded the deleter in the argument list. The `make_unique` would then just have to identify that element and use it to construct the deleter where required.

Comment: @Barry, of course. Should have noticed this.@Mankarse, I think a type tag would make inferring the deleter impossible, turning make_unique into a function too verbose to be actually useful? (instead we should simply use unique_ptr's constructor) Correct me if I'm wrong, though.

Answer (score 6):

For [`unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr), the deleter is part of the type:

```
template <
    class T,
    class Deleter = std::default_delete<T>
> class unique_ptr;
```

As such, when you're constructing an object, you need to specify its type. The line you're writing:

```
std::unique_ptr<int> x(new int, custom_deleter);
```

is equivalent to:

```
std::unique_ptr<int, std::default_delete<int> > x(new int, custom_deleter);
```

And you cannot construct a `std::default_delete<int>` from `custom_deleter`.

The only way to *infer* the deleter type is to use template deduction on that part too:

```
template <typename T, typename Deleter>
std::unique_ptr<T, Deleter> make_unique_ptr(T* ptr, Deleter deleter) {
    return std::unique_ptr<T, Deleter>(ptr, deleter);
}
```

Comment: that's exactly what I would've done for `std::make_unique`, don't see any reason why it's not implemented like that.

Comment: @vsoftco [copied from above] How would that work? It has to take an argument pack to construct the T. How would you differentiate which one of Args... is the Deleter?

Comment: maybe with a `std::piecewise_construct` / `std::forward_as_tuple`

Answer (score 3):

It cannot infer the type of the deleter, because `unique_ptr` by default has no state devoted to a deleter: the default deleter is stateless.

In your case, the deleter needs a pointer's worth of state, so it cannot 'fit' within the `std::unique_ptr`'s state (which is just a pointer to a `T`).

This makes `unique_ptr` a lightweight, nearly cost-free replacement for an owning pointer.

Deductin could be done, but it would have to change the type of the resulting `unique_ptr`.

In comparison, `shared_ptr` always has state capacity for a deleter, two different atomic counters, and a pointer to value.  It is heavier weight, and not a cost-free replacement for a pointer.