# assymetry between std::shared_ptr and std::unique_ptr constructors

Tags: c++

During C++03 we did not have `unique_ptr`, so I had used the `tr1::shared_ptr` instead.

Now, in C++11, in such cases, I am replacing calls like this:

```
tr1::shared_ptr<X> o(new X);
```

with

```
std::unique_ptr<X> o(new X);
```

Unfortunately, for some reason, I cannot replace cases containg a deleter, where the deleter is a function:

```
void special_delete(Y *p) { ... }

tr1::shared_ptr<Y> o(new Y(), special_delete); 


std::unique_ptr<Y> o(new Y(), special_delete);  // does not compile
std::unique_ptr<Y, std::function<void(Y*)> > o(new Y(), special_delete);  // this compiles
```

Why does this happen?
Is there a homogeneous way I can replace all shared_ptr constructors with unique_ptr constructors ?

I have created **this**, but I am not really happy about it..

```
template <class Y>
using unique_ptr_with_deleter = std::unique_ptr<Y, std::function<void(Y*)> >;

unique_ptr_with_deleter<Y> o(new Y(), special_delete);  // this compiles
```

Comment: Related: [Why does unique_ptr take two template parameters when shared_ptr only takes one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21355037/why-does-unique-ptr-take-two-template-parameters-when-shared-ptr-only-takes-one)

Comment: @JesperJuhl: Except precisely *not* in the OP's case.

Answer (score 4):

The `shared_ptr` template type-erases the deleter. There's only one single type `shared_ptr<T>` for any kind of deleter you want. It's a very heavy-weight (and expensive) tool.

By contrast, the `unique_ptr` makes the deleter part of the type, and so it has no dynamic call overhead. A `unique_ptr<T, D>` is very nearly as cheap as a raw pointer.

Note that you can construct a `shared_ptr<T>` from a `unique_ptr<T, D>` rvalue for *any* deleter type `D`.

---

Random commentary on your solutions: neither solution is great. Using the function pointer as the deleter needlessly makes the deleter a *dynamic* part of your unique_ptr state. The `std::function` case is even worse, using an entire type-erasing virtual dispatch mechanism for the deletion -- keeping in mind that you know *statically* how to delete!

The better solution is to make the deleter part of the *type*, not part of the value, by writing your own type:

```
struct YDeleter { void operator()(Y* p) { special_delete(p); } };

std::unique_ptr<Y, YDeleter> p(new Y);   // or presumaby some special factory
```

That way, the entire deletion logic is known at compile time and can be inlined as much as possible, without *additional* function call indirection.

Comment: And possibly something like: `template <auto f> struct Deleter { template <typename T> void operator()(T* p) {f(p);} };` and then `using YDeleter = Deleter<&special_delete>;`.

Comment: Isn't this answer pretty much what the OP had in the first place? (Which I myself saw nothing wrong with).

Comment: @PaulSanders: How so? My deleter is stateless, the OP's is not.

Comment: Oh right, I see it now, thanks.  I myself did it the same way as you a while back, don"t know why I forgot that.

Answer (score 2):

You should supply deleter type

```
std::unique_ptr<Y, decltype(&special_delete)> o{new Y{}, &special_delete};
```

Note that replacing `tr1::shared_ptr<X> o(new X);` with `std::unique_ptr<X> o(new X);` is not a good idea and is not supposed to work in general. `std::unique_ptr` is more like a replacement for `auto_ptr`.

Comment: Yes, but why don't I have to do this instantiation in std::shared_ptr ?

Comment: @GrimFandango Because they handle deleters differently. For `unique_ptr` deleter is a part of the type while `shared_ptr` embeds deleter into implicitly created shared state so deleter type is not part of the type. For `shared_ptr` different shared states might be instantiated based on deleter supplied into constructor.

Comment: I like the use of `decltype` here - very neat.

Comment: _`shared_ptr` embeds deleter into implicitly created shared state_ right, I understand that now, but why does it do it differently, there seems to be no obvious reason?  I guess it's just history,  `shared_ptr` dating back to C++03 and all.  I think we could say they got it wrong back then.