# How does a shared_ptr store deleter?

Tags: c++, function, generics, shared-ptr

I can't understand how a `shared_ptr` can store the deleter that I gave to it.

Initially, using a `shared_ptr<int>`, i thought it might use an `std::function<void(int*)>`, but i can give, as a deleter, any kind of function (or callable objects), as long as the first parameter is a `int*`.

How can `shared_ptr` do this?

I'm sorry if this is a silly question, I'm new to C++, forgive me!

Edit:
The question is: how can I do something like that? What should I use? Any example? Or it is a very advanced topic?

Comment: Do you want to know about your particular compiler and library?  (If so, tell us which you are using)  Or what the C++ Standard says about all conforming implementations?

Comment: I would know how can i do something like that. I will edit the message.

Comment: @Toccio: That behavior is enabled by templates. It's an advanced topic. Kudos for the question, it's reasonable and well put.

Comment: @Jon: I know how template works (at least, the bases), do you think this isn't enough? My C++ book (C++ Primer) ask me to implement a shared_ptr =/

Comment: If you want just the basis of type erasure, go and implement `any` first. The rest is just adding details.

Comment: This application is the poster child for type erasure. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/6324694/

Comment: [This article](https://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/tutorials/470449/mixing-static-and-dynamic-polymorphism) might be of interest to you, and there is a section on type-erasure, which is the technique used here. It's a bit of an advanced topic, but not that advanced, every good C++ programmer who uses templates or generic programming should learn to be very comfortable with straddling the line between static and dynamic polymorphism.

Comment: @Nemo thanks! It is very helpful that link, and i think i have understood at least the basics of type erasure! Thanks very much!

Answer (score 10):

The deleter, as well as the allocator, are type-erased. The shared pointer manages a dynamically allocated, private, templated control object, which is accessed through a polymorphic base and which stores all the type-specific state and functionality.

The implementation of `std::function` uses similar ideas, since it is also a type-erasing dynamic manager class, but both are typically implemented entirely separately.

The upshot is that both classes are comparatively "expensive" and should only be used when they are genuinely necessary. Otherwise, cheaper, non-polymorphic non-dynamic solutions are usually preferable.

Answer (score 5):

> I can give, as a deleter, any kind of function (or callable objects), as long as the first parameter is a `int*`.

No, not really.  The `std::shared_ptr` constructor has the following contract, found in section 20.8.2.2.1 (`[util.smartptr.shared.const]`):

> ```
> template<class  Y,  class  D>  shared_ptr(Y*  p,  D  d);
> template<class  Y,  class  D,  class  A>  shared_ptr(Y*  p,  D  d,  A  a);
> template  <class  D>  shared_ptr(nullptr_t  p,  D  d);
> template  <class  D,  class  A>  shared_ptr(nullptr_t  p,  D  d,  A  a);
> ```
>
> Requires:  `p`  shall  be  convertible  to  `T*`.   `D`  shall  be  CopyConstructible.   The  copy  constructor  and destructor  of    `D`  shall  not  throw  exceptions.   **The  expression  `d(p)`  shall  be  well  formed**,  shall  have well defined behavior,  and shall not throw exceptions.  A shall be an allocator (17.6.3.5).  The copy constructor and destructor of A shall not throw exceptions.
>
> Effects:  Constructs a `shared_ptr` object that owns  the object `p` and the deleter `d`.  The second and fourth constructors shall use a copy of `a` to allocate memory for internal use.
>
> Postconditions:  `use_count() == 1 && get() == p`.
>
> Throws:   `bad_alloc`,  or  an  implementation-defined  exception  when  a  resource  other  than  memory could not be obtained.
>
> Exception safety:  If an exception is thrown, `d(p)` is called.

This requirement is a lot stronger than that the first parameter of the deleter must be the right type.  It has to be the only parameter (without a default argument), such that `d(p)` is legal.  This is slightly more flexible than `std::function<void (int*)>`, because the return type can be anything, but it's also more constrained with respect to exception guarantees.

If your compiler doesn't catch you when you provide a deleter with multiple required parameters, the standard library implementation is doing something rather wrong.

As far as how to implement it, take advantage of the fact that it must be CopyConstructible.  For example, the following lambda should work pretty nicely, and be assignable to `std::function<void(void)>` (the CopyConstructible guarantee ensures that capture by value works):

```
[d, p] { d(p); }
```

Comment: @hvd: I said "has to be the only parameter without a default argument".  In your example, it is.

Comment: "If your compiler doesn't catch you when you provide a deleter with multiple required parameters, it's doing something rather wrong." Not necessarily. Violating a *Requires* clause causes UB. The compiler is not required to diagnose it.

Comment: @T.C.: In general that is true.  In this case, something extremely screwy would have to be going on in the library (like casting function pointers -- yikes!) in order for there not to be a `d(p)` call that causes a compile error.