# std::make_shared with throwing dtor and libc++ doesn't compile

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, clang++, libc++

Here is very basic code:

```
#include <memory>

class foo
{
public:
    ~foo() noexcept(false) { }
};

int main()
{
    auto x = std::make_shared<foo>();
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled as follows:

```
g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp          <-- OK
clang++ -std=c++11 test.cpp          <-- OK
clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ test.cpp          <-- FAIL
```

When compiling with libc++, it failes with:

```
/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:3793:7: error: exception specification of overriding function is more lax than base version
class __shared_ptr_emplace
    ^
/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:4423:26: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::__1::__shared_ptr_emplace<foo,
    std::__1::allocator<foo> >' requested here
    ::new(__hold2.get()) _CntrlBlk(__a2, _VSTD::forward<_Args>(__args)...);
                        ^
/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:4787:29: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
    'std::__1::shared_ptr<foo>::make_shared<>' requested here
    return shared_ptr<_Tp>::make_shared(_VSTD::forward<_Args>(__args)...);
                            ^
exc.cpp:11:19: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::make_shared<foo>' requested here
    auto x = std::make_shared<foo>();
                ^
/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:3719:13: note: overridden virtual function is here
    virtual ~__shared_weak_count();
```

I thought it might be a bug in libc++, but wanted to check here before I file a bug.

Comment: dunno what the standard says - but it's flat out wrong to make a dtor throw.

Comment: is there a motivation behind this?

Comment: @Mordachai thank you but that's irrelevant to the question

Comment: shared pointers store the address of the objects dtor.  chances are your code is violating the requirements of that function pointer - it must not be "more lax than base version"

Comment: @Mordachai you cannot get the address of a destructor.

Comment: @imreal yes, you can: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25655145/how-does-a-shared-ptr-store-deleter
(and that's how shared_ptr works)

Comment: @Mordachai What makes you think `shared_ptr` stores a pointer to the types destructor? It has a pointer to a custom callable deleter but that's not the same thing.

Comment: @Mordachai Yes `shared_ptr` allows to optionally pass a deleter (that could be a function pointer), but by default it simply invokes the object's destructor.

Comment: Your code compiles fine as-is on visual studio 2015 version 14.0.24720.00 Update 1

Comment: For what it's worth, **[util.smartptr.shared.const]** says `delete p` shall not throw (where `p` is a raw pointer passed to `smart_ptr`'s constructor). It doesn't say that a destructor cannot have a `noexcept(false)` specification though - just that it shall not act on it.

Comment: @Mordachai so... one cannot have a shared_ptr of a class with throwing dtor? ... just trying to understand where the problem is

Comment: @InnocentBystander As Igor has mentioned, actually *throwing* from the destructor of a `shared_ptr` results in undefined behavior.  The standard does not seem to say "and this means the destructor cannot be `noexcept(false)`", but one could argue that this is a defect in the standard.

Comment: I am still not fully convinced. Looking at [util.smartptr.shared.create] it does not say anything about not throwing from the dtor. Additionally, `auto x = std::shared_ptr<foo>(new foo);` compiles fine with both g++ and clang++/libc++ (although it doesn't mean it's not UB). I suppose it could be chalked up to a defect in the standard.

Comment: @InnocentBystander sorry - I am not a language rules guru - so I'm just throwing out what little understanding I do have to see if that helps?  Sorry.  I'm reasonably certain you can create a shared_ptr to a T with a ~T that can throw - it has to for legacy code.  I'm sure none of my code explicitly uses except(false) - though I conform to the understanding that such is what is really required for any sort of sanity - so... I guess I don't have the answer you need.  sorry. g/l

Comment: @InnocentBystander that code compiles under g++ 4.9.2.

Comment: The behavior is undefined if *any* destructor operation invoked by the standard library throws an exception, period. There's blanket wording in the library introduction to that effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the question(s) boil down to:

- Should this compile?  A: Maybe
- What happens if you run it? A: You get undefined behavior.

AS @T.C. says, [res.on.functions]/2 states:

> In certain cases (replacement functions, handler functions, operations on types used to instantiate standard library template components), the C++ standard library depends on components supplied by a C++ program. If these components do not meet their requirements, this International Standard places no requirements on the implementation.
>
> In particular, the effects are undefined in the following cases:
>
> [skip]
>
> -- if any replacement function or handler function or destructor operation exits via an exception, unless specifically allowed in the applicable *Required behavior:* paragraph.

Standard-ese aside, throwing from a destructor has been a bad idea for a long, long time (at least since C++98). If there is an exception in flight, and you throw another exception during stack unwinding, that's a quick trip to `std::terminate()`.

Comment: Well, OP's code should compile and work. The requirement is for the dtor to *not throw*, not for it to be `noexcept`.