# Hold any kind of C++ template class in member variable

Tags: c++, templates, member

I have got two classes.

The first class (A) is builded with an template.

```
template <class T>
class A
{
    public:
        T value;
};
```

The second class (B) should have an object of class A as member variable. Like this:

```
class B
{
    public:
        A<int> value;
};
```

But now i want to use **any** kind of template-class in class A. Not only *int*.
Apparent I can't declare a (member-)variable which contains any kind of a class.
So, I need something like this:

```
class B
{
    public:
        A<*> value;
};
```

Is there any (clean) solution for this problem?

-- Greeting from Germany, Bastian

Comment: Why do you need such a thing? [Describe the goal, not the step](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#goal).

Answer (score 7):

You cannot have a single class `B` with "any" member object, because `B` has to be a well-defined class, and `A<T>` is a *different type* for different types `T`. You can either make `B` a template itself:

```
template <typename T>
class B
{
  A<T> value;
};
```

or you can take a look at [`boost::any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/any.html), which is type-erasing container for arbitrary types (but making use of it requires a certain amount of extra work). The `any` class only works for *value* types, though, it's not completely arbitrary.

Comment: "type-erasing"? really? how does `any_cast` work without type?

Comment: @Nim: "type-erasing" in the sense that the type of the `any` object does not depend on the type of the things you put in. Compare to `shared_ptr<T>`, which can be constructed with a custom deleter or custom allocator, neither of which become part of the type.

Comment: @Nim: A tell-tale for a type-erasing class is a private nested polymorphic class from which templated subclasses are derived. Take a look at `any.hpp`, that's what's going on (called `placeholder`).

Comment: @Nim: [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6122094/building-boostoptions-from-a-string-boostany-map/6123962#6123962).

Answer (score 4):

The simplest solution would be to make all A variants ineherit from a common interface, even if it's empty :

```
class IA{}

template <class T>
class A : public IA
{
    public:
        T value;
};

class B
{
    public:
        IA* value;
};
```

Now, the associated costs:

- interactions with value are limited to the IA interface;
- if you try to cast to get the real type, that mean that you know the real type, so it's of no use and make A type a parameter of B becomes really easier to use.
- there are runtime costs associated to runtime inheritance

Advantage :

- it's easily understood by other developers
- it naturally limit the types possible to some specific ones
- it don't use boost (sometimes, you just can't)

So to do better there are other less simple solutions but that are simple enough to be used :

If you can use boost, boost::any, boost::variant and boost::mpl might be base of solutions.

Boost any can be used as a safe replacement to void*. The only problem with this is that you can have ANY type, like if the type was a template parameter of the B class.

Boost variant might be used successfully if you know all the types that A can be.

MPL might be helpful if you just want to set a list of possible types and make sure your members apply only to them. You can do a ton of things with MPL so it really depends on your exact needs.

Answer (score 2):

You've got two choices, I think. The first is to parameterize your class over the type parameters of the instance variables:

```
template <class T> struct B
{
  A<T> value;
};
```

The other option is to declare `value` as a `void*` pointer. (But that's probably not what you want).

Answer (score 1):

yes, it's already been done. [boost::any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/any.html).

Answer (score 1):

I think it helps to understand, that templated classes create an entirely new and seperate class for every type you use with it.  For instance, `Vector<int>` and `Vector<float>` are as separate as the classes `VectorInt` and `VectorFloat`.

For class B, you are basically asking that the `value` variable either be `A<int>` or `A<float>`, which is the same as saying you want value to either be a "A_int" or "A_float".  And to accomplish that you... well, use another template!