# C++ choose template type of class member in constructor

Tags: c++, class, c++11, templates, dynamictype

I'm trying to define template class inside of nontemplate class, below you may see the code of what i'm actually trying to do (it doesn't compilable for obvious reason). The main question is how can I realize that using C++11 (preferable) or C++14?

1. Actually I've got solution using [std::variant](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) or same function from the BOOST library, but I need to know another way to solve that.
2. I found old similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7154602/hold-any-kind-of-c-template-class-in-member-variable), and answer by Anne Quinn sounds valuable (he suggest to declare subclasses for each type I need), but how to apply that in code right?

Code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>

enum Type {
    INT16,
    UINT32
};

template<typename T>
class Buffer {
public:
    Buffer(uint32_t paramSize) {
        buffer.resize(paramSize);
    }

private:
    std::vector<T> buffer;
};

class Foo {
public:
    Foo(Type paramType, uint32_t paramSize) {
        switch(paramType) {
        case UINT32:
            buffer = Buffer<uint32_t>(paramSize);
            break;
        case INT16:
            buffer = Buffer<int16_t>(paramSize);
            break;
        }
    }

private:
    Buffer buffer;
};

int main() {
    Foo var(INT16, 30);

    return 0;
}
```

**UPD1:** answer by @user2308211 seems work, but I got two problems with that. In case I'm copying object Foo and original object destroys for some reason (moving out of scope for example), copy will stay with pointer to nowhere. Second one is how to retrieve my buffer through Foo class.

**UPD2:** shared_ptr resolves problem with copying, but then copy will store the same object, in case you wanna modify them independently, use copy constructor as shown in answer. As for access to original buffer, void pointer allow you to retrieve pointer to vector, then you should static_cast it to your type.

Thanks!

Comment: You could make your `Buffer` polymorphic and inherit it from a single non-template base.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I need to see some example of realization, sounds new to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a base class with all the required functions for `Buffer` as pure virtual.

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>

enum Type {
    INT16,
    UINT32
};

class BufferBase {
public:
    virtual void someFn()=0;
    virtual ~BufferBase() {}
};

template<typename T>
class Buffer:public BufferBase {
public:
    Buffer(uint32_t paramSize) {
        buffer.resize(paramSize);
    }

    void someFn() override {
      //functionality.
    }
    ~Buffer() {}

private:
    std::vector<T> buffer;
};

class Foo {
public:
    Foo(Type paramType, uint32_t paramSize) {
        this->bufferType = paramType;
        switch(paramType) {
        case UINT32:
            buffer = new Buffer<uint32_t>(paramSize);
            break;
        case INT16:
            buffer = new Buffer<int16_t>(paramSize);
            break;
        }
    }
    ~Foo() {
        delete this->buffer;
    }
    Foo &operator=(const Foo &other) {
        this->bufferType = other.bufferType;
        switch(bufferType) {
        case UINT32:
            buffer = new Buffer<uint32_t>(*static_cast<Buffer<uint32_t>*>(other.buffer));
            break;
        case INT16:
            buffer = new Buffer<int16_t>(*static_cast<Buffer<int16_t>*>(other.buffer));
            break;
        }
        return *this;
    }
    Foo(const Foo &other) {
        *this=other;
    }

private:
    BufferBase *buffer;
    Type bufferType;
};

int main() {
    Foo var1(INT16, 30), var2(UINT32, 25);
    var1 = var2;

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: I've updated the answer with a copy constructor.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Here only one problem, in case i'm copying object Foo and deleting original, copy will got pointer to nowhere.

Comment: You need to update the copy constructor for `Foo` to perform a deep copy. That will give you correct behavior. If you want to optimize further, you could consider creating a move constructor, which would reassign pointers.

Comment: Using a shared pointer is justified only if you are absolutely sure of what you're doing. My understanding is that you may want to copy Foo objects and modify them independently. A shared pointer won't give you that.

Comment: Well yeah, that exactly I want how buffer should acting, it should be thread safe and available through copies, so basically that should be the same object. Last one problem that I can't get buffer data out of Foo class, i'm able to do this only through public pointer.