# Is there a way get an integer out of boost::any if you don't know if original type was signed or unsigned

Tags: c++, boost, boost-any

I'm using `boost::any` in combination with `boost::any_cast<>` to write some framework code which should take a set of arguments, almost like a function call, and convert them into an array of `boost::any` types.

So far everything has been working great, except in places where it is hard to predict if the number the caller gives me is going to be signed or unsigned.  A lot of code in our existing product (windows based) uses `DWORD` and `BYTE` data types for local variables so if one of those variables is used, I get unsigned type.  However if a constant is hardcoded, the most likely it'll be a simple number in which case it will be signed.

Since I can't predict if I should do `any_cast<int>` or `any_cast<unsigned int>`, 50% of the time my code that reads the `boost::any` array will fail.

Does anyone know if there's a way to just a number out of `boost::any` regardless if original type was signed or unsigned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a way; `boost::any` does the simplest form of type-erasure, where the type must match exactly. You can write your own `boost::any`-like class that supports the additional features you want. I've [previously demonstrated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6122094/building-boostoptions-from-a-string-boostany-map/6123962#6123962) how this can be done.

Failing that, you can:

1. Have two code paths, one for each sign. (Switch to signed path if `any_cast<unsigned T>` throws.)
2. Try unsigned, and if that throws, try signed and cast, use a single code path.
3. Just let the unsigned `any_cast` throw if it's signed, and force the user to cope.

However, each of these isn't really that good. Do you really need `boost::any`? Perhaps you want `boost::variant` instead, if you're expecting a certain list of types.